# Setting static parameter types in benchmarks

Tags: pallet, runtime, benchmarking, benchmark

There is very little information to be found on `static` parameter types. All I could find is a [docstring](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/polkadot-v0.9.13/frame/support/src/lib.rs#L351) that says: In testing, `StaticArgument` can be altered later: `StaticArgument::set(8)`.

I need to alter a parameter in benchmarking code to be able to benchmark a specific path Pallet config:

```
#[pallet::config]
pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
  type HeadersToKeep: Get<u32>;
}
```

In the runtime code the parameter is declared as `static`:

```
parameter_types! {
    pub static HeadersToKeepArgument: u32 = 1000;
}

Passed to the config:

impl my_pallet::Config for Runtime {
    type HeadersToKeep = HeadersToKeepArgument;
}
```

Now when I want to set it's value to execute a benchmark code:

```
benchmarks! {

  benchmark_with_pruning {

    let _ = T::HeadersToKeep::set(3);

    ...

  }: foo(RawOrigin::Signed(caller.clone()))

  verify {
   ...
  }

}
```

```
75 |         let _ = T::HeadersToKeep::set(3);
   |                                   ^^^ function or associated item cannot be called on `<T as pallet::Config>::HeadersToKeep` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `<T as pallet::Config>::HeadersToKeep: frame_support::storage::generator::StorageValue<_>`
           which is required by `<T as pallet::Config>::HeadersToKeep: frame_support::StorageValue<_>`
           `&<T as pallet::Config>::HeadersToKeep: frame_support::storage::generator::StorageValue<_>`
           which is required by `&<T as pallet::Config>::HeadersToKeep: frame_support::StorageValue<_>`
           `&mut <T as pallet::Config>::HeadersToKeep: frame_support::storage::generator::StorageValue<_>`
           which is required by `&mut <T as pallet::Config>::HeadersToKeep: frame_support::StorageValue<_>`
```

Comment: Can you explain why the `Get` implementation needs to be dynamically changed? The value should be constant when implemented in your runtime, and thus, when you run benchmarks, you will get exactly the results for the value that put. In summary, I think you might be doing something wrong here.

Comment: tl;dr it's just easier this way. I need to benchmarks two paths: happy path and *other path*. Other path is invoked when there is more items (in the storage) than the `Get` parameter (1K here). It's a convoluted setup to get it over 1k and trigger that other logic, and the number of elements won't impact the compute complexity. It does not need to be dynamically changed though, conditional compilation is also a possibility, so I might just go with that.

Comment: Yeah I don't think it will be possible to do what you want here for actual benchmarks. For tests, there are some tricks, but these would fail in the real runtime environment. And for good reason. Some of why this is not possible is that we use rust and type safety to ensure that things we expect to be constant are

Answer (score 1):

Other than Oliver's answer, I want to point out that you are likely having the wrong mental model here.

Your benchmarking code receives `T`, including `T::HeadersToKeep` and all the other configurations as *input*. Your benchmarking code must behave and tested without needing to alter these values.

For example, your mental model should be like this: You should write your benchmarking code such that if `HeadersToKeep` has an impact on the weight, in one runtime where it is configured to a higher value, it is captured.

Nowhere in this scenario you should need to alter `HeadersToKeep` within a benchmark. Again, `T` is the input of your benchmark, and it a way for you to *know the final configuration of the runtime*, not to alter it.

Lastly, as noted [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/afb74de23dfe2994e7ce38c0870efb9734e966f7/frame/support/src/lib.rs#L473), `set` is only available in `std`, meaning that while you could mis-use it in native execution of benchmarks, you cannot use it in WASM at all.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, if you want to know how the benchmark result goes after you change the constant, you can just change that, and then benchmark this pallet.

Because when you modify the constant and deploy the new runtime code, you also need to do this benchmark again, right?

Comment: in this case not really, no - I'm conditioning the constant value on the `runtime-benchmarks` feature atm to run the benchmark

Comment: Then how about just make it as a storage value, and change it before benchmark ?

Comment: Invoking the whole storage machinery for one integer seems like an overkill (maybe even an anti-pattern). In any case I think I have an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand your problem here, but you can do:

```rust
benchmark_with_pruning {
    // Components must be named with a single char. _ does not work.
    let c in 0 .. 3;
    HeadersToKeepArgument::set(c);
} …
```

Note that you have to define the `parameter_types` in the benchmarking and then use it in your mock file as `super::benchmarking::HeadersToKeepArgument`. The other way around does not work as the benchmarking cannot access the mock.